# How can I convert a data frame from long into wide format and transforming the names?

Tags: r, formatting

I have a data frame containing EEG recordings from 20 participants via 16 channels, and I want to transform it from long format into wide format.

These are the first few rows from the data frame:

```
Channels   Cor_Delta    Cor_Theta     Cor_Alpha     Cor_Beta    Cor_Gamma
1        Fp1   7.9282950   3.17715528   0.883063653  0.180184333  0.067005367
2        Fp2   2.9008879   2.31265276   0.717646766  0.441049175  0.345908377
3         F3  15.6804218   4.53794901   1.339479012  0.485670209  0.207540419
4         Fz  12.6632245   4.43202836   1.300727466  0.339465222  0.160385067
5         F4   9.6073893   3.08714939   0.955651050  0.301290566  0.169550498
6         T7  17.0112358   2.46593290   1.456122077  0.351035950  0.266752174
7         C3  12.2618370   2.96911538   0.982053471  0.359852506  0.191636925
8         Cz   6.6116757   2.11342152   0.868712081  0.252456282  0.195759867
9         C4   9.7271019   3.24718010   0.976788952  0.252235549  0.183452156
10        T8   3.1581446   0.83358213   0.371337997  1.977366357  1.327675472
11        P3   8.3972751   2.18149063   0.803456599  0.295080918  0.189495796
12        Pz   7.3811724   3.31112269   0.879818222  0.478939159  0.325100702
13        P4   8.4947662   2.23617536   0.928800870  0.518971886  0.341175444
14        O1   7.0518179   1.74794126   1.494911077  0.903115417  0.580304045
15        O2   4.7430335   1.69239359   2.257335741  1.884407127  1.471184452
16        Oz   7.0614880   2.40628208   2.833822160  0.890961434  0.452513118
17       Fp1  30.4463886   5.21125125   2.340720294  0.851459242  0.458680504
18       Fp2  10.1880423   4.25035151   1.731034762  0.388603747  0.066859716
19        F3  28.4452173   6.55304646   1.873673957  0.652491405  0.324053469
....
```

Some more specifications:
The dimensions are [672   6]
The columns are called: Channels, Cor_Delta, Cor_Theta, Cor_Alpha, Cor_Beta, Cor_Gamma.

Example: Assume the two first rows from the data frame:

```
    Channels   Cor_Delta    Cor_Theta     Cor_Alpha     Cor_Beta    Cor_Gamma
1        Fp1   7.9282950   3.17715528   0.883063653  0.180184333  0.067005367
2        Fp2   2.9008879   2.31265276   0.717646766  0.441049175  0.345908377
```

The result should be:

```
Cor_Delta_Fp1  Cor_Theta_Fp1  Cor_Alpha_Fp1  Cor_Beta_Fp1  Cor_Gamma_Fp1 Cor_Delta_Fp2 Cor_Theta_Fp2  Cor_Alpha_Fp2 Cor_Beta_Fp2 Cor_Gamma_Fp2 ...... 
 7.9282950   3.17715528   0.883063653  0.180184333  0.067005367 2.9008879   2.31265276   0.717646766  0.441049175  0.345908377 .....
```

The resulting data frame should be 20x80 (80 predictor variables, and 20 participants). Can someone help me to perform this transformation in R?

Comment: Can you share your data.frame using `dput` instead? Just the first lines are enough. It'll be easier for people to reproduce your problem.

Comment: That said, you can use `tidyr::pivot_wider`.

Comment: Using `dplyr`, we can do `quux %>% mutate(rn = row_number(), .by=Channels) %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = rn, names_sep = "_", names_from = Channels, values_from = -c(rn, Channels))`. This is "classic" pivoting, with the (common) requirement that we add the `rn` (here) column. Another option is with the `data.table` package, as in `as.data.table(quux)[, rn := seq(.N), by="Channels"] |> dcast(formula = rn ~ Channels, value.var = c("Cor_Delta", "Cor_Theta", "Cor_Alpha", "Cor_Beta", "Cor_Gamma"))`. Good luck!